# Stop Matlab from changing numbers to other characters

Tags: matlab, settings, eeglab

I have a Matlab Script where I am processing some data in a loop. After setting the directories (DIRs) outside of the loop, I set the subject ID numbers in a vector, then load the file to work on:

`SUB = {1040 2001 (and so on...)}`

```
 for i = 1:length(SUB)
    
    %execute statements and catch errors 
    try
 
    %load the setfile
    EEG = pop_loadset('filename',[SUB{i} '_WIT_postprocessing.set'],'filepath', [DIR2 '/']);
```

For specific people, I keep getting an error. For example, for subject 1040, the program (EEGlab) cannot load their data because Matlab changes 1040 to A.

`SUB{i} '_WIT_postprocessing.set'`

`ans 'A_WIT_postprocessing.set`

This continues with other numbers as well. For example, SUB{2001} becomes a small square. What setting is causing this? How do I turn it off?

Comment: you should explicitly convert each numeric subject ID to a string before concatenating it with the rest of the filename using `num2str(SUB{i})`. This should prevent MATLAB from interpreting numeric values as characters in the filename and causing the issue you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the list of numbers to a sting solved this issue:

`SUB = {"1040" "2001"}`

Comment: You've used backticks here which isn't valid MATLAB syntax, they should be either `'single quotes'` for chars or `"double quotes"` for strings.